# How to get the authenticated user's email address in node.js AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I have an Angular app that uses the AWS javascript SDK, and can successfully login with Facebook and Google.  I am able to create the Cognito identity and I see the identity in my Federated Identity pool.  I am also able to use my IAM authenticated API endpoints (I see the user's cognitoId in the Lambda I am calling).

I want to use the user's email address as the key in the database (DynamoDB), so I am trying to figure out how to access the user's email address from a trusted source, either Cognito (preferred) or the Authentication Provider's JWT.

What is the best way to access the user's email address?

**Update:** On the client side (javascript) I'm using Federated Identities with Google and Facebook tokens.  The social login is working, and I can get authenticated with Cognito just fine, passing the Logins:

```
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-1:****',
    Logins: {
      'accounts.google.com': authResult['id_token']
    }
});
```

I then do `AWS.config.credentials.get()` and I can get things like `AWS.config.credentials.identityId`, but I can't find accessToken or the methods to call to get the JWT.  I believe I need to call `result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken()`, but I can't find it.

All of the examples where they get the accessToken seem to use `.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails())`, but the details include a user name and password (not Federated login).

Answer (score 10):

**tldr**; Send the accessToken post-authentication to lambda and use CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.getUser() to obtain the attributes.

I spent hours fumbling around with the ID tokens and from what I can tell, the only way to get a user's actual identity is to use a combination of the accessToken provided from a successful authentication and the [getUser](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#getUser-property) call from the identity provider. This only appears to be for the NodeJS SDK and nothing else.

I am using Amazon's API Gateway for my application and Lambda in the background. After a successful authentication, you can access the accessToken and feed it to a Cognito server provider. **From there, you can save the details locally, but it presents a large security issue if you plan to use this information on the backend**. Since it's local storage, the user can just adjust the user attributes to whatever they like.

To get around this, you can pass the accessToken to the lambda function directly and perform the same process on the server. Doing this ensures that the user attributes have not been manipulated or tampered with. Be sure to use HTTPS on your API to avoid leaking the accessToken to others who could use the AWS SDK to get the internal details.

```js
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

AWS.config.region = '<REGION-ID>';

exports.lambda_handler = function(event, context) {
  var accessToken = event['accessToken'];
  var provider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
  provider.getUser({
    AccessToken: accessToken
  }, function(err, obj) {
    context.succeed({
      'user': obj
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond.  The issue I'm having right now is that I don't know how to get the accessToken.  I'm going to update the question with a sample of what I am using to get the credentials.  All of the examples I can find seem to use the username/password credentials, whereas I am using Federated Identities with Google and Facebook provider.

Comment: if `event` is empty?